# make_shared with custom new operator

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, shared-ptr

This is probably a duplicate, but I cannot find the solution anywhere.

I have source code like this:

```
struct Blob{
    //...    

    static void *operator new(size_t size_reported, size_t size) {
        return ::operator new(size);
    }
};
```

I use it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Blob> blob;
// ...
size_t size = calcSize(); // it returns say 231
Blob *p = new(size) Blob();
blob.reset(p);
```

Can I change the code somehow so I can use `std::make_shared` or `std::allocate_shared` so I have `single allocation` instead of `two allocations`?

---

### Update

I was able to eliminate the `new` and simplify the code to the following:

```
struct Blob{
    //...    
};

std::shared_ptr<Blob> blob;
// ...
size_t size = calcSize(); // it returns say 231

// allocate memory
void *addr = ::operator new(size);

// placement new
Blob *p = ::new(addr) Blob();

blob.reset(p);
```

It does exactly the same thing, but I think now it is more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, change it to `std::shared_ptr<Blob> blob = std::make_shared<Blob>();`, and you'll get a single allocation.

Comment: but this is "custom" (overloaded) new operator?  `Blob *p = new(size) Blob();`

Comment: Your overloaded operator is only used for `new Blob`, and it cannot be used in anything else. Overloading `operator new` is generally a pretty useless feature, since it doesn't integrate with any part of the standard library. I'd go as far as to call it a misfeature of the language to even offer this; it seems that we've learned by now that the way to customize memory allocation is via the library (i.e. via allocators).

Comment: So, does that mean that a custom allocator should be written and used here, if Nick wants to ensure the overloaded new is used?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: No, it means that nobody should ever overload `operator new`, and if you want custom allocation semantics, write a custom allocator and use that for everything.

Comment: @KerrekSB - ok, how this may be done with custom allocator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what come up with.

Since there is no way to pass size to the allocator, you can do it via `global variable` or `class member`.

In both cases the solution is not elegant at all and is rather dangerous - disaster waiting to happen now or later when code needs to be maintained.

Another unexpected problem may happen if `allocate_shared` place the `shared_ptr` control block **after** the buffer class.

In such case there will be clear buffer overflow, because `sizeof(buffer)` will report size like 1 byte or so.

Once again - the code is working, but will have issues in the future for sure.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <memory>

// ============================

class buffer{
public:
    buffer(const char *s){
        strcpy(x, s);
    }

    char x[1];
};

// ============================

template <typename T>
struct buffer_allocator {
    using value_type = T;

    buffer_allocator() = default;

    template <class U>
    buffer_allocator(const buffer_allocator<U>&) {}

    T* allocate(size_t n) {
        void *p = operator new(n * sizeof(T));

        printf("Allocate   %p, (%zu)\n", p, get_size());

        return (T*) p;
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) {
        delete p;

        printf("Deallocate %p, (%zu)\n", p, get_size());
    }

    size_t get_size(){
        return size;
    }

    void set_size(size_t size){
        this->size = size;
    }

private:
    size_t size = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const buffer_allocator<T>&, const buffer_allocator<U>&) {
  return true;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const buffer_allocator<T>& a, const buffer_allocator<U>& b) {
  return !(a == b);
}

// ============================

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    buffer_allocator<buffer> ba;

    const char *s = "hello world!";

    ba.set_size( strlen(s) + 1 );

    auto b = std::allocate_shared<buffer>(ba, s);

    printf("Pointer    %p\n", b.get());

    printf("%s\n", b->x);
    printf("%zu\n", b.use_count());
    auto b1 = b;
    printf("%zu\n", b1.use_count());

    return 0;
}
```