# Implementing reference counting

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I am developing an application that uses several (say 5M) objects.

Each object is composed of single `std::shared_ptr` that points to `blob` in memory. Every memory `blob` have different size.

I want to minimize allocation, so I want to do something like `std::make_shared` or `std::allocate_shared`, that makes single allocation.

It seems this is not possible (probably possible with Boost)
[make_shared with custom new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904439/make-shared-with-custom-new-operator/31908134)

Next option is to implement ref count myself :) . I am aware this is no easy at all and better have two allocations, than some hidden bug, but I want to explore the possibility.

Is there some ready implementation of something like this?

I can also find this:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#ref-count-simple

Comment: Please, use the [tag:c++] tag. Asking for libraries is off-topic anyway.

Comment: It sounds like you really want your own memory management system, not reference counting system (XY problem). And I doubt you could do a better job than your compiler vendor already has.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - this was really very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that allocate_shared with a custom allocator is indeed your answer.

Writing an allocator is not trivial, but not that difficult either. The concept is laid out here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator

a quick google search for "c++ memory pool allocator" revealed a number of ready-written examples such as this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html

(search for "pool allocator" on this page)

Comment: I tried this in other question, but I did not found reliable way to pass the object size to the allocator - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904439/make-shared-with-custom-new-operator/31908134 . The code I posted works, but is awful.

Comment: not sure I understand. An `allocator<T>` will have a method called `allocate(n)` which will allocate memory for n objects of type T. The `allocator` knows the size of T because it can call `sizeof(T)` under the covers.

Comment: T have variable size. size reported by sizeof() is always wrong.

Comment: @Nick there must be something you're misunderstanding. T is a template, it represents 'some object'. It will be the same size each time T represents a given object. What are you trying to achieve? pre-allocation of all memory or dynamic pool-allocation (i.e. freeing all memory at once at the end)?

Comment: pls check this, bit long, but I can not do it shorter.
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/293349/key-value-store-development-porting-to-modern-c

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any work. If I understand you right then what you are looking for is boost intrusive_ptr, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html.

Reference counting with only one allocation per object.

Comment: make_shared also does only one allocation - it allocates the object and the control block as a single tuple.